# LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, lnk2019

Никак не получается устранить ошибку "unresolved externals".Помогите, пожалуйста, распознать ее. Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "math.h"
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;


float fA(int x, int y);
float fB(int x, int y);
float fC(int a, float b);
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int x, y, z;
    float A, B, C;
    cout << "x=";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "y=";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "z=";
    cin >> z;
    A = fA(x, y);
    B = fB(x, y);
    C = fC((int)A, B);
    cout << C << endl;

}

float fA(int x, int y, int z)

{
    if ((pow(x, 3) + pow(M_E, 2 + y) == 0) || ((pow(pow(y, 4) + pow(x, 4), 3) == 0)))
    {
        cout << "Помилка";
    }
    else {
        float a;
        a = ((pow(z + pow(x, 2), 2)) / (pow(x, 3) + pow(M_E, 2 + y))) / ((pow(sqrt(pow(abs(z + x), 3)), 4)) / (pow(pow(y, 4) + pow(x, 4), 3)));
        return (a);
    }
}
float fB(int x, int y)
{
    float b;
    b = sqrt(sin(x) + pow(cos(y), 2)) + tan((555 * (M_PI)) / 180);
    return (b);
}
float fC(int a, float b)
{
    float c;
    c = (b / (sqrt((2 * a) + b))) + a;
    return (c);

}
```

Comment: не "math.h", а <cmath>

Comment: Тогда у меня M_PI  и  M_E не считываются

Comment: math.lib добавить наверное надо в список подключённых библиотек или как там она называется.